# How do you survive thunderstorms?

Tags: diablo-iii

Elite monsters with the new Thunderstorm affix rain lightning bolts down directly on your head. With other affixes, there are usually ways to predict and dodge their attacks. The monster gives you some kind of indication about where the attack is coming and you can prepare before it actually hits you.

Is there such a mechanism with thunderstorms? How can you deal with thunderstorm enemies most effectively?

Comment: Sounds like the dreaded "Storm Herald" mod from Path of Exile. The bolts tend to "close-in" on your current position, so if they're anything alike moving continuously is usually the best way to deal with it, rather than standing still beating on the monster.

Comment: Thunderstorms I usually just ignore.  They're not too bad when you can leech the damage straight from the source.

Comment: there's also a legendary that confers electricity immunity.  I don't remember the name though.

Answer (score 5):

Thunderstorm damage is quite limited. As long as you have an adequate health reserve you can continously ignore the lightning storm effect (as Frank mentioned) and just stand in it and use your life leech / life on hit to outheal the damage. The thunderstorm is an area of effect mechanic, which is instantly placed; just move out the area of effect and the effect is no longer relevant for you until cast at a new place.

Otherwise: most classes have some sort of evasion mechanic. Vault or Shadow Form with Demon Hunter, ... Use it and just get out of the area of effect.

Comment: Is there some visual indicator of the center of the area of effect? I haven't noticed it yet.

Comment: @StrixVaria the lightning bolt always strikes the dead center of the aoe.  There's also a glowing area signifying where the damage stops.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: I'm not aware of any warning for thunderstorms. Maybe the damage ramps up over time? Not sure.

How to deal with them: As somebody else pointed out, if you have a lot of Life On Hit then they don't hurt too badly, at least at the Torment 1 level I'm playing at, so you may choose to just outlast them... but alternatively, MOVE! As long as your enemy is a melee fighter (most, though not all, enemies) they will probably follow you away from the storm.